# Checking for similar numbers in the 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, logic

I have to find out the similar no. in the diagonal, column, row or triangle in a 2D array and if same no. are found then the condition is true and I want to know the position of the similar no. where they are found because later on, I want to replace these locations with my marker no.(-1).

For Example, these are the instance of the array which are **true** because they have same no. in the given pattern

Instance: True

```
001

001

001
```

Instance: True

```
100

010

001
```

Instance: True

```
000

111

000
```

Instance: True

```
000

100

110
```

Instance: True

```
000

010

110
```

For Example, these are the instance of the array which are **false** because they don't have same no. in the given pattern
Instance: False

```
101

010

000
```

Same goes for another possible pattern too. I choose the recursive approach to check the neighbours and then their neighbours but the results are different and it is checking for same no. in the whole and if it found 3 no. anywhere then return true.
Here is my code snippet

```cpp
    int var=0;

    bool CheckSame(int row,int col,int num)

    {
        if (var==3)

            return true;// 3 same numbers found

        if (var!=3 && row==0)

            return false;//reached first row but didn't find

        if (arr[row][col]==num)
        {
            var++;
        }

        if (col==(MAX-1))//right corner
        {
            if (arr[row][col]==arr[--row][col]==arr[row][col])
                CheckSame(--row,col,num);//upper
            CheckSame(row,--col,num);//left
            CheckSame(--row,--col,num);//D-left
        }
        else if (col==0)//left corner
        {
            CheckSame(--row,col,num);//upper
            CheckSame(row,++col,num);//right
            CheckSame(--row,++col,num);//D-right
        }
        else//other
        {
            CheckSame(row,++col,num);//right
            CheckSame(row,--col,num);//left
            CheckSame(--row,col,num);//upper
            CheckSame(--row,++col,num);//D-right
            CheckSame(--row,--col,num);//D-left
        }
    }
```

Comment: `or triangle`  Please explain what you mean by "triangle".

Comment: Also ask a question. This isn't a blog site.

Comment: By Triangle I mean right angle triangle structure of similar numbers in 2D array of any dimension and it can be anywhere in the array.

Comment: @juanchopanza This code finds same number 3 times in the array but I want to find similar numbers close to each other i.e consecutive as mentioned in the array instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are going down the right track by using recursive and checking the neighbors. You need to get rid of your static variable var and your recursive method should return a bool value. The static variable var is causing lots of problems in combination with the recursive functions.

Comment: I have changed the function return type and static variable. This code works and it finds same number 3 times in the array but I want to find similar numbers close to each other i.e consecutive.